How to change the order of input methods (keyboard languages) in Windows 11?
In Windows 11, I  switch keyboard languages with WIN + SPACE  It  cycles through all installed keyboard layouts (input languages). How can I change the order in which it cycles through the layouts ? I.E., I want it  to switch e,g  to English and not to German from / after  Spanish.   Changing the  order of languages in Settings does not do it, but only messes  up the interface language.

Try changing the Registry numeric value names in the following two locations:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload`

HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload



Press Windows, type reged, and select Regedit.

Move to key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload [or cut-and-paste in location bar].

Edit the name of the value. Since values under the same key cannot have the same name, use a placeholder, and then switch that last name (requiring one additional step). In the example shown:

Press F2 on value named 1 and change it to 0.
Press F2 on value named 2 and change it to 1.
Press F2 on value named 0 and change it to 2.


Repeat for key HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload.


Hopefully, the order is now as you desire. However, Microsoft has moved this location in the past, and may do so in the future. In that case, search the Registry for the layout key:

Open Regedit as above.
Move to the root location, Computer.
Press CtrlF to open search.
Remove check marks from Values and Data.
Enter keyboard layout (case insensitive), expand the key and look for Preload (not all keys have the sub-key), make modifications as above, and repeat for additional locations found.
Not all locations are editable; some are just backup entries and may be ignored.

N.B.
Use care when editing the Registry. Export the key being modified to a .reg file, so that it can be restored i there is an issue. This should be a relatively simple and benign change, though.

Tanks! Should I ADD those values? My current registry does not seem to have these values.

Actually in my  current setup there is no  Preload  folder under HKCU\Keyboard Layout. Should I add it?

@AlexanderGelbukh, oops! There are additional Registry locations that might need to be modified; the answer has been edited to show that. Sorry about that error.

Thank you! No, in my setup under HK\ CURRENT USER \ Keyboard Layout the only entries are: Default and Attributes, Should I add a new  entry Preload?

Look for "preload" under other Keyboard Layout keys. You could try adding it, though I do not know whether it would work... It likely will do no harm.
